# User-friendly boolean printing in PHP

Tags: php

In the below code 'resAvailability' might be equal to 1 or 0. Is it possible to update this code in such a way that 1 produces 'Yes' and 0 results in 'No'?

```
   <?php foreach ($result as $row):?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['resAvailability']; ?></td>
    <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: Please mark one answer as accepted if it was helpful for you.

Comment: There is time threshold in which I can accept the answer. Pls wait few minutes.

Comment: Oh .. sorry! Somehow confused the time of question and answers.. Sorry again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
echo $row['resAvailability'] ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

This is called the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this? Very basic stuff

```
if($row['resAvailability'] == 1)
{
    echo "Yes";
}
else
{
    echo "No";
}
```

**edit**
Emil his code is effectively the same is this, though since you asked such a basic question I thought you were quite new and in my opinion this is easier for beginners ;) though I would definitly go with Emil's way (less code and all that).

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I would do it:

```
echo ($row['resAvailability'] == 1) ? "Yes": "No";
```

Be aware that 1 will also validate as true and 0 as false so in actual fact you don't need the `== 1` in my example as either way it will run as:

Is $row['resAvailability'] true, return yes, else return no.